# How to validate path params and explicitly set status codes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, http-status-codes

I am trying to set up a super simple RESTful endpoint (as an `ApplicationController`) that does simple path param validation and that returns a hardcoded JSON response:

```
{
  "foo" : "123",
  "bar" : {
    "whistle" : "feather",
    "ping" : "pong"
  }
}
```

The URL being hit is `GET http://localhost/widgets/${widgetId}/${fizzbuzzId}` where both `${widgetId}` and `${fizzbuzz}` are expected to be positive integers.

I'm trying to figure out how to check the value of `${widgetId}` and `${fizzbuzzId}` and throw a 400 if they aren't positive integers. I'm also trying to figure out how to return the hardcoded `response` string as the HTTP response entity with status code 200 if the two path params survive validation:

In the `routes.rb`:

```
resource :widgets
```

And then the controller:

```
class WidgetsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    if(params[:widgetId].to_i <= 0 || params[:fizzbuzzId] <= 0) {
      render json: { "error" : "bad path params" }, status: :not_found
      return
    }

    response = %(
      {
        "foo" : "123",
        "bar" : {
          "whistle" : "feather",
          "ping" : "pong"
        }
      }
    )

    render json: response, status: :ok 
  end
end
```

When I run this I get:

````
myuser:myapp myuser$ curl -k http://localhost:3000/widgets

SyntaxError at /widgets
==============================

> syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
/Users/myuser/myapp/app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>
      render json: { "error" : "bad path params ...
                              ^
/Users/myuser/myapp/app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
...ad path params" }, status: :not_found
...                               ^
/Users/myuser/myapp/app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end

app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb, line 3
----------------------------------------------------

``` ruby
    1   class WidgetsController < ApplicationController
    2     def show
>   3       if(params[:widgetId].to_i <= 0 || params[:fizzbuzzId] <= 0) {
    4         render json: { "error" : "bad path params ID" }, status: :not_found
    5         return
    6       }
    7   
    8       response = %(
```

App backtrace
-------------

 - app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb:3:in `'
 - app/middleware/catch_json_parse_errors.rb:8:in `call'

Full backtrace
````

Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Comment: To return repose: `render json: respose, status: :ok`
For the params, rails has the `params` keyword. You can try to print it with  `puts params`  and see what it contains.

Comment: Thanks @linnal (+1) - please see my updated code that incorporates you're feedback. Is there a cleaner way to verify that the params are integers **and** positive? Also can you confirm that my 400 error response is correct? Thanks again enormously!

Comment: @smeeb on a side-note, instead of writing your response as a JSON string directly, you can use a Hash, which will make interacting with your response object a lot easier, and use Rails's `Hash#to_json` method to generate a JSON string version of it. In fact if `response` is a Hash object this will be called automatically when you do `render json: response`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not necessary, or particularly desirable to tell us whether you are new at using Ruby or Rails; We don't really care. We do care whether you asked a good question, showing research and effort. "[ask]" and the linked pages along with "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)" go into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether your params are positive integers by using this:

```
>> "23".to_i > 0
=> true
>> "foo".to_i > 0
=> false
```

So you could adept this for your params via `params[:widgetId].to_i > 0`
Does that make sense to you?

Also if you want to return your error response, you need to return "early" otherwise the controller will complain about a double render:

`render json: { "error" : "bad input" }, status: :400 and return`

Comment: Thanks @Holger Forhloff (+1) - I updated my question to contain your suggestion! Regarding `params[:widgetId].to_i <= 0`, will this be false even if `params[:widgetId].to_i` returns `false`? Or would `false <= 0` be a double-negative, resolving to `true`?!

Comment: Also now that I'm able to start running the code I'm seeing errors in your suggestion. Any ideas as to what the fix is? Thanks again so much!

Comment: @smeeb `params[:widgetId].to_i` returns 0 if `:widgetId="string"` 
What errors are you seeing? BTW: you can run `rails c` and try little commands from terminal :)

Comment: Thanks @linnal (+1) please see my updated question with the exact error...doesn't seem to like my error response json...any ideas?

Comment: @smeeb updated your code. There should not be `and`, you need return so that you do not render twice, otherwise rails complains.

Comment: Thanks again so much @linnal (+1) - please see my updated error message, Rails is still not liking the syntax for some reason!

Comment: @smeeb I think the problem is this `json: { "error" : "bad path params" }`, something that happens (If I find out why, I'll write you here, probably something with how rails parses params) , just assign the json to a variable: `response = { "error" : "bad path params" } ` and than `render json: response, status: :not_found`